# ESLint disable `no-dupe-keys` doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm using Typescript and ESLint in my project and I am stuck on a problem with the error: `An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.`

I just want to disable checking for this error in the line but I don't know how to do it.

This looks like the `no-dupe-keys` rule from the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-dupe-keys#rule-details) but for some reason it doesn't work in my project.

**testFetch.ts**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export function testRequest() {
  const url:string = 'https://example.com/api';
  
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  const test_camel = 'sd'

  const body = {
    "key[0]": "arr_val_1",
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-dupe-keys
    "key[0]": "arr_val_2",
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    "key[1]": test_camel,
  }

  fetch(url, {body})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.error('error:' + err));
}
```

I know... but such weird body params are required.

As you can see on the screenshot linter highlights it anyway.

[image]

**.eslitrc.cjs**

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  root: true,
  rules: {
    "no-dupe-keys": "error",
    camelcase: "error",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [ 
        "test/*", 
        "dist/*",
        ".eslintrc.cjs"
    ],
  // "noInlineConfig": true,
};
```

---

Works perfeclty in the [playground](https://eslint.org/play/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyplc2xpbnQgbm8tZHVwZS1rZXlzOiBcImVycm9yXCIqL1xuXG52YXIgZm9vID0ge1xuICAgIGJhcjogXCJiYXpcIixcbiAgICAvLyBlc2xpbnQtZGlzYWJsZS1uZXh0LWxpbmUgbm8tZHVwZS1rZXlzXG4gICAgYmFyOiBcInF1eFwiXG59OyIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZW52Ijp7fSwicnVsZXMiOnt9LCJwYXJzZXJPcHRpb25zIjp7ImVjbWFGZWF0dXJlcyI6e30sImVjbWFWZXJzaW9uIjoibGF0ZXN0Iiwic291cmNlVHlwZSI6Im1vZHVsZSJ9fX0=) but not in the real project:

[image]

Comment: what is it you're trying to accomplish with dup keys?

Comment: just curious why you need this type of data ????

Comment: This error comes from ts and not eslint. Also, it's impossible to store two identical keys in a javascript object anyway. Only the last one will be used

Comment: As I wrote above, it is not up to me. Such weird request parameters are required to by the API in a particular case. I can make such a request in Postman and everything works fine, but I can't do anything about it in my TS project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It turns out that `no-dupe-keys` rule cannot be disabled at all?

Comment: The api probably expects `x-www-form-urlencoded` because it's impossible to have two identical properties in json

Comment: Sorry, these parameters go in the query string, I'm guessing like an array.

Comment: @mr.incredible it's working on my vscode for index.js file. Maybe issue with ts

Comment: Thank you for checking, but it should be .ts file

Answer (score 1):

It's IMPOSSIBLE to have an object in javascript with two identical keys. So no option of eslint or typescript will give you what you are trying to do.

The API probably requires a form-data like structure.

An example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#formdata

```
import fetch, { FormData } from 'node-fetch'

const httpbin = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('key[0]', 'Hello, world!')
formData.append('key[0]', 'new name.txt')

const response = await fetch(httpbin, { method: 'POST', body: formData })
const data = await response.json()

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Just copying a code block from documentation 1:1 without explanation is not a good answer

Comment: Thank you for the example, you are wright

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, key should be unique you can't send 2 keys with the same name.
I'm guessing you want to send 2 values for the `key[0]` as query params to the backend.
For that, you can send an array in query params as well.
In the backend get the value of the key `key[0]` and traverse it as an array.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export function testRequest() {
  const url:string = 'https://example.com/api';
  
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  const test_camel = 'sd'

  const body = {
    "key[0]": ["arr_val_1","arr_val_2"],
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    "key[1]": test_camel,
  }

  fetch(url, {body})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.error('error:' + err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have mistake in my code example. It should be query string but not the body params, sorry for that.

Comment: I think the above code looks fine to you.
It would we great if you accept the answer and upvote it if you are satisfied with the answer:))

Answer (score 0):

In the image you provided, following the error message, there's a reference to `ts1117`. This indicates that the source of the error is TypeScript, not eslint. To bypass this error, you should disable TypeScript for that specific line as follows.

```
  const body = {
    "key[0]": "arr_val_1",
    //@ts-ignore
    "key[0]": "arr_val_2",
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    "key[1]": test_camel,
  }
```